# setTimeout appears to execute too fast

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I've been fiddling around with setTimeout and setInterval, and I cannot get the code to execute the way I would like it to. My goal is to create a setInterval, which calls once every three seconds, and have it clear after ten seconds. However, when I run the code in firebug, the only thing I get is a number, which I assume is the id of setInterval because every time I execute the code, the number increases.

```
var intID = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("I've been called");},3000);


setTimeout(clearInterval(intID), 10000);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This statement:

```
setTimeout(clearInterval(intID), 10000);
```

means, "call the function 'clearInterval' passing the value of variable 'intID', and then pass the return value of that and the number `10000` to the function 'setTimeout'."

In other words, you're **calling** the function "clearInterval" and then passing the returned value to `setTimeout()`.

Instead, pass `setTimeout()` a function:

```
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(intID); }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are **not** setting up the interval like this:

```
setInterval(console.log("I've been called"), 3000);
```

If you did, `console.log` would be called immediately -- even *before* `setInterval`, since it's an argument to `setInterval` and arguments have to be evaluated before calling the function that uses them.

So *why are you setting up the timeout like this*?

```
setTimeout(clearInterval(intID), 10000);
```

This causes the exact same kind of problem as above.

Just do the same thing you did when setting up the interval instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(intID); }, 10000);
```